# Decimate A Mesh To An Explicit Number of Vertices and Faces

Tags: python, subdivision-surface

I am building a machine learning dataset from a collection of 3D models. Training the models requires that the mesh have the same number of faces and vertices for every model in the dataset, which requires me to treat my data.

I have cobbled together a method of achieving this from PartSegmentationToolbox ([link](https://github.com/LSnyd/PartSegmentationToolbox)), which manages to obtain the same number of faces per model by using a Subdivide and Decimate Modifier.

However, I notice the number of vertices differs between objects I apply the method to. I am a bit puzzled, as I thought the number of vertices would be directly proportional to the number of faces.

Is there a way that I can obtain the same number of vertices and faces at the same time using an input model? If not, what method could be applied to obtain the result I am looking for?

```
def Subsurf(mesh):
    # Subdivide the mesh
    mod = mesh.modifiers.new(name='Subsurf', type='SUBSURF')
    mod.subdivision_type = 'SIMPLE'
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)
    # Triangulate the mesh
    mod = mesh.modifiers.new(name='Triangulate', type='TRIANGULATE')
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)


def Simplify(mesh, target_faces):
   
    nfaces = len(mesh.data.polygons)
    # Check if number of faces less than required, and subdivide until achieved
    while nfaces < target_faces:
        Subsurf(mesh)
        nfaces = len(mesh.data.polygons)

    mod = mesh.modifiers.new(name='Decimate', type='DECIMATE')
    mod.decimate_type = 'UNSUBDIV'
    mod.use_collapse_triangulate = True

    # Set the decimation ratio
    ratio = target_faces / float(nfaces)
    mod.ratio = ratio
    
    # Apply the modifier
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)
```

Comment: `F + V - E = 2`  (Euler's Formula)    :)   ... I think we need to know if your objects are always manifold?

Comment: EDIT: Yes, the meshes are non-manifold.

Comment: Tricky because so open-ended.. do your meshes have anything in common? Maybe an example?

Comment: Sorry: I am not sure quite what you mean. There are a thousand meshes, with vertices varying from 1000-10000 vertices.